# Format date and time but exclude "today date" in Swift?

Tags: swift, date, dateformatter

My code:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .short
        dateFormatter.locale = .current
        lblDateTime.text = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
```

The problem is I need `dateFormatter.dateStyle = .none` for today date. How to resolve it correctly? Is it possible to avoid manual date calculations to determine "today date"?

Comment: It's not exactly what you want, but how about `dateFormatter.doesRelativeDateFormatting = true`?

Comment: @Sweeper look at vadian's answer. He understood me. Unfortunately `doesRelativeDateFormatting` just converts date into "yesterday", "today" and etc.

Comment: Okay, I guess using `Calendar` doesn't count as "manual date calculations"? It does in my book :-)

Comment: @Sweeper I was afraid that I should convert date to the "start of day" date and calulate difference between these two dates. `Calendar.isDateInToday` resolves this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if the given date is in today, `Calendar` provides an appropriate API

```
let isDateInToday = Calendar.current.isDateInToday(date)
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short
dateFormatter.dateStyle = isDateInToday ? .none : .short
dateFormatter.locale = .current
lblDateTime.text = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
```

If you can live with a four digit year and non-padded day and month, this is an alternative

```
let isDateInToday = Calendar.current.isDateInToday(date)
lblDateTime.text = date.formatted(date: isDateInToday ? .omitted : .numeric, time: .shortened)
```

Answer (score 1):

From `iOS 8.0` you could use the `isDateInToday(_:)` method from `Calendar`.

#### Code Example

```swift
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

...

dateFormatter.dateStyle = Calendar.current.isDateInToday(date) ? .none : .short
```

You'll find further informations for this method also in the Apple documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar/2293243-isdateintoday